# How to disallow all non-numeric input in console during an input prompt?

Tags: c#, validation, input, console

Talking console here.

The idea is that if user presses any key except numbers(the ones above the letter keys, and numpad) during an input prompt in the console, then nothing will be typed. Its's as if console will ignore any non-numeric key presses.

How would one do it the right way?

Comment: Do you care about the console's fancy editing features, like up-arrow to repeat previous input?

Comment: Yep. That would be neat.

Comment: Ah, but what if the previous input was non-numeric? (grin) And what about left- and right-arrows? Do you want to support those, or would digits and backspace be good enough?

Comment: You know what. Screw those fancy features.

Answer (score 9):

Try the ReadKey method:

```
while (processing input)
{
  ConsoleKeyInfo input_info = Console.ReadKey (true); // true stops echoing
  char input = input_info.KeyChar;

  if (char.IsDigit (input))
  {
     Console.Write (input);
     // and any processing you may want to do with the input
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about the don't-echo flag.

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert System.ConsoleKeyInfo to Char

Comment: It shows a unicode for the number I input. Instead I want the actual input to be assigned to an object variable variable. Example if I type in 7 it assign 55 to the variable x, but it's suppose to assign 7.

Comment: @Precision: You need to convert from Unicode char's to numeric values yourself in the `// and any processing...` bit. Use `TryParse` or just subtract 48.

Comment: If you're going to subtract 48, you'd better explicitly check for `>= '0' && <= '9'`, rather than using `IsDigit` (since `IsDigit` will allow anything that Unicode calls a digit).

Comment: @Joe White: Very true! TryParse will be a more portable method.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static void Main(string[] args) {

    bool inputComplete = false;
    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    while (!inputComplete ) {

        System.ConsoleKeyInfo key = System.Console.ReadKey(true);

        if (key.Key == System.ConsoleKey.Enter ) {                
            inputComplete = true;
        }
        else if (char.IsDigit(key.KeyChar)) {
            sb.Append(key.KeyChar);
            System.Console.Write(key.KeyChar.ToString());
        }
    }

    System.Console.WriteLine();
    System.Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString() + " was entered");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This little experiment works like that:

```
static void Main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        var key = Console.ReadKey(true);
        int i;
        if (int.TryParse(key.KeyChar.ToString(), out i))
        {
            Console.Write(key.KeyChar);
        }
    }
}
```